# how to go bottom of the div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my focus don't go to bottom of  the div using jQuery ?

http://jsfiddle.net/VqR6Q/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){

        alert('---')
 window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    })   


})
```

Comment: works fine to me. to the bottom of the body you mean...

Comment: Not working in my fiddle check

Comment: if your result pane has no scroll bar, then it has nothing to scroll to, make the result pane smaller in height

Comment: I provided you fiddle please check

Comment: @naveensharma its jQuery not jquerry.

Comment: why would you post a fiddle for 1 line of code you can copy-paste to your console???

Answer (score 1):

USe following

fiddle ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqR6Q/3/)***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
    })   


})
```

Comment: please use fiddle ..can we do without animate

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
var fullContainer = document.getElementById('fullContainer');
fullContainer.scrollTop = fullContainer.scrollHeight;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqR6Q/4/)

The reason your code won't work is that you are scrolling the `window.body` with the height of `document.body`.
You want to scroll the element with the scrollheight of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scrollTop`, not `scrollTo`:

```
$('#fullContainer').scrollTop($('#preRealTimeContents').height());
```

Remember to use the inner element to calculate the distance of the scroll.

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/VqR6Q/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){               
$('#fullContainer').scrollTop($('#preRealTimeContents').height());
    })   


})
```